# Is it possible to call new in SystemVerilog outside an assign statement?

Tags: system-verilog

This is how I usely call `new` in SystemVerilog:

```
class A;
endclass

A a = new();
```

But sometimes, I don't need a local object, I just want to send it directly to a function taking an `A`. Is there a way to call the new function explicitly here:

```
function use_a(A obj);
endfunction

use_a(new());  // <--- How to write this call to specify which new to call?
use_a(A::new());   // <--- new not expected here :(
```

Comment: I believe the answer is no. But why do you want to do it anyway? Why not just call new inside the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, SystemVerilog's syntax does not allow this. The special `new` method is not a static method, and a class handle has to exist in some variable because of the way class memory management is defined. You could get around this by wrapping `new` around a static method:

```
class A;
static function A create();
  create = new();
endfunction
endclass

...

use_a(A::create());
```

BTW, the UVM has `create` methods in the BCL and you almost never need to call `new()` directly.